# How would I go about searching for Users querying multiple associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, search

Okay. Let's say there is a User model with multiple join tables.

User

```
has_many :languages
has_many :skills
has_many :languages, through: :user_langauges
has_many :skills, through: :user_skills
```

If I hit an endpoint with params like

```
"user"=>
  { "email"=>"test@123.com",
   "languages"=>"["French", Spanish]",
   "skills"=>"["accounting", "leadership"]"
}
```

How would I search for users that match the above? My main concern is how do I search for users that match BOTH associations of "languages" and "skills". Is the best to take all the users and compare which users are the same? Something like:

```
french = French.users
leadership = Leadership.users
french & leadership # => "users that exist in both?"
```

Obviously, there is more logic, but I feel like that general idea is taxing and inefficient. But I'm sure rails has thought of a more elegant way, which is why I need direction from you rails masters :)

edit: I have a Psql DB if that matters.

Comment: If you go something like this may be it would work: `User.joins(user_skills: :skills, user_languages: :languages).where("conditions")`. And if you want to go with the above solution mentioned you may do it like: `french.where("leadership condition")`.

Comment: @Deep you don't need to add the intermediate tables to the joins, this is taken care of by the has_many through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't want to compare the users in Ruby. It will load lots of data and won't be performant if you have lots of users/skills/languages.

This is what a DB is for. Check the AR guides to learn how to query the DB: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
I also suggest you read up on SQL because AR only helps you to build SQL queries. But the power comes from your DB.

Here is a rough sample how it might work:

```
User.joins(:languages, :skills).where(skills: {name: ['Ruby', 'Marketing']}, languages: {name: 'French'}).uniq
```

Assuming: user, skill and language have an attribute `name` adjust for your schema.

This will search for Users that have: (skills Ruby OR Marketing) AND speak French.

If you wan't to have: ruby AND marketing AND french, then the query get's more complex.

UPDATE:
As mentioned, the AND combination is more complex. You will need to use GROUP BY and HAVING or can give subqueries to count the skills a try. Here is raw SQL query that will work:

```
SELECT users.* FROM (
SELECT users.* FROM "users"
INNER JOIN "user_skills" ON "user_skills"."user_id" = "users"."id"
INNER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."id" = "user_skills"."skill_id"
WHERE skills.name IN ('Ruby', 'Marketing')
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) users
INNER JOIN "user_languages" ON "user_languages"."user_id" = "users"."id"
INNER JOIN "languages" ON "languages"."id" = "user_languages"."language_id"
WHERE languages.name IN ('German', 'French', 'English')
GROUP BY users.id, users.name, users.created_at, users.updated_at
HAVING COUNT(users.*) = 3
```

The numbers (2, 3) must be the number of matches you need (2 skills, 3 languages).

Comment: Okay that helps a lot including the resource. Doing "Ruby" AND "Marketing" AND "FRNCH" is what I was going for. Hopefully I can get the answer from the docs you provided. I'm trying to build a tool to narrow down employee skills with a search engine where a user can "filter" the emplyees based on the query.

Comment: I managed to get the query to work for rails. But now I'm just wondering how "okay" it is to be having such a long query, is that just natural for querying joing? The model I'm working with is pretty hefty as I'm making a way for the client to find their employees.

What if I wanted to add another join. Is there a better way to approach that? Or just follow suit and add more queries to that line?

Comment: "Worker.select('workers.*').joins(:months).group('workers.id').where(search_params).having('count(months.id) >= ' + havingMonths ).uniq"